# Crystal Reports without database & dataset

Tags: database, vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset

is it possible to use Crystal Reports without the need to dataset & database ?

i have a gui with a lot of textboxs and functions that returns a lot of variables that i need to report , i manged to use Crystal Reports without database , but no luck without dataset

---

sorry for bad English :(

Comment: my problem with dataset is that is hard to add all the variables and info into it , and takes a lot of coding :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use ADO.NET objects, you create a class which has the "columns" as properties, then you populate an array of this class in your code.
When that's done you especify your array as the datasource in your report

```
    report.SetDataSource(objectList.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without a dataset,

use the below mentioned code directly

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

     Dim fname20 As TextObject
                fname20 = objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("rptdate")
                fname20.Text = "your text"
```

Its simple that's what you need